# SQL not saving the time of a DateTime via EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, datetime

I'm using EF to save a date time.

The Date is being saved to the database but not the time. I'm using the `date` type. However, the SSMS (2012 express) field only shows `dd/MM/yyyy` (no time)

Reading it back it reads something like `26/07/2014 00:00:00`

I'm assuming it's showing 00:00:00 because that is how it is being saved (despite not showing).

To save the entry, I'm just assigning a DateTime to my property.

```
myEfModel.Date = DateTime.Now;
```

I also tried (to ensure the number of digits wasn't confusing SQL on the save)

```
var timeNow = DateTime.Now;
timeNow.AddMilliseconds(-timeNow.Millisecond);
myEfModel.Date LastUsed = timeNow;
```

Searches on SO shows most people claiming `they have no problems saving DateTime.Now via EF`

Why won't the time save?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `DATE` datatype in SQL Server **2012** specifically saves **only the date** (no time) - it's a **feature** not a bug.... (the `DATE` datatype was introduced in SQL Server 2008 specifically to be used when you only care for the date, e.g. "hire date" or things like that, when the time portion usually just gets in your way).

See the [MSDN documentation Date and Time Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) in SQL Serer Books Online for more details....

If you need time, too, use `DATETIME2(n)` in your database table instead (where the `n` can have a value between 0 and 7 and defines how many fractional second decimal points you need; 0 = accuracy to the second, 7 = accuracy to 100ns)

Comment: @DaveRook: if feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.